Maximum determinant of binary matrices with special properties
Let $A$ be an $n$-by-$n$ binary matrix (all elements are in $\{0,1\}$). It is known that the determinant of $A$ is bounded by $O(n^{n/2} / 2^n)$. I am looking for tighter upper bounds for matrices with special properties. Particularly:

Is there a tighter bound when each row has exactly $k$ ones, for some integer $k>0$?

Is there a tighter bound when, for each two different rows, their elementwise product has exactly $k$ ones, for some integer $k>0$? (note, according to this question and its answer, such matrices are always invertible).


EDIT: In particular, is there an upper bound for any of these families, that is polynomial in $n$?

Perhaps related, and probably already known to you:  https://doi.org/10.1002/rsa.20109

I'd also like to drop this link here for everyone who visits this page: http://www.bohemianmatrices.com/

I'll give a partial answer to your Question #2. If you know $k$ and also how many entries are equal to $1$ in each column, you can actually compute the absolute value of the determinant exactly.
By the answer you linked to, we know that
$$
A^TA = \begin{bmatrix}v_1 & k & \cdots & k \\ k & v_2 & \cdots & k \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ k & k & \cdots & v_n \end{bmatrix},
$$
where $v_j$ is the number of ones in the $j$-th column of $A$. In particular, $k \leq v_j \leq n$ for all $j$. So we can write
$$
A^TA = k\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T + D,
$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is the all-ones vector and $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are $v_j-k$, which are are between $0$ and $n-k$ (inclusive).
By the matrix determinant lemma, we can compute
\begin{align*}
\det(A)^2 = \det(A^TA) & = \det(k\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T + D) \\
& = (1 + \mathbf{1}^T D^{-1}\mathbf{1})\det(D) \\
& = \left(1 + \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{v_j-k}\right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^n (v_j-k)\right),
\end{align*}
as long as $D$ is invertible. The only way that $D$ can fail to be invertible, assuming $A$ is invertible, is if there is a single index $j$ for which $v_j = k$ (this is explained in the same answer linked before). WLOG I will assume that this special index is $j = 1$. By a continuity argument, in this case we have
$$
\det(A)^2 = \prod_{j=2}^n (v_j-k).
$$
Putting all of this together gives the following explicit formula for $|\det(A)|$ (again, assuming that if any $v_j = k$ occurs, it occurs when $j = 1$):
\begin{align*}
|\det(A)| = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{\prod_{j=2}^n (v_j-k)}, & \text{if $v_1 = k$} \\
\sqrt{\left(1 + \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{v_j-k}\right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^n (v_j-k)\right)}, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
You can use this to get bounds or whatever is most well-suited to your purposes. For example, if you don't know exactly what the $v_j$'s are, you can use the fact that $0 \leq v_j-k \leq n-k$ to derive the bound
$$
|\det(A)| \leq \sqrt{n+1}(n-k)^{n/2}.
$$

Interesting! it is still exponential in $n$, but uesful when $k$ is large.

Yeah. Slightly more generally, it would be useful if the gap between $k$ and the number of $1$s in each column is small (if there are at most $m$ ones in each column, you get a bound of roughly $(m-k)^{n/2}$).

In case 1) a cheap bound is $|{\rm det}(A)|\le k^n$. That's because $A/k$ is a stochastic matrix and therefore has all its eigenvalues in the closed unit circle. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem

Thanks! This bound is better than the general bound if $k < \sqrt{n}$.

Same bound applies to the permanent, more specifically: $$|\det(A)|\leq \mathrm{per}(A)\leq k^n$$

The paper https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1804.02897 gives the better bound $\vert\det A\rvert\le k^{(n+1)/2}((n-k)/(n-1))^{(n-1)/2}$.
